# What is the best way to calculate the total cart items in the Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

while working on an e-commerce app I need to calculate the total items in the cart. Cart is saved in the redux store, and the count state is also there to count the items.

I have tried different solutions like:

1)Reducing the state.cart in the Cart Reducer. But this was not working fine as I tried to reduce the state.cart on every add or remove item from the state.cart And it is not taking the immediate state.cart value, hence not deleting the items correspondingly.As following

```
    if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {

        return {
            ...state, 
            cartItems: action.payload,
            total : state.cartItems.reduce((acc,val) =>{
            acc += val.count;
            return acc
        },0)
      }
    }
    
    else if(action.type === REMOVE_FROM_CART){
        return {
            ...state,
            cartItems: action.payload,
            total : state.cartItems.reduce((acc,val) =>{
                acc += val.count;
                return acc
            },0)
        }
    }
```

2)Second I create an action creator getTotal() and dispatched it from the useEffect hook. It's working totally fine but the only problem which I think is major one, console is giving max depth call stack error.As

Action.js file

```
export const getTotal = () => dispatch =>{

    return dispatch({type: GET_TOTAL})
}
```

reducer.js file

```
    else if(action.type === GET_TOTAL){
        return {
            ...state,
            total: state.cartItems.reduce((acc,val) =>{
                acc += val.count;
                return acc
            },0)
        }
    }
```

Navbar.js file

```
  useEffect(() =>{
    dispatch(getTotal())
  })

// -------

   <Link to="/cart">
     <Badge badgeContent={total} color="primary">
       <ShoppingCartOutlined />
     </Badge>
   </Link>
```

So What is the best way to calculate the total items in the cart or if somehow can I handle the useEffect hook to avoid the call stack error?

Looking forward :)
thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `dispatch` for calculated values.

Instead, create a helper function for calculation logic:

```
const getCartTotal = ({cartItems}) => {
  return cartItems.reduce((acc,val) =>{
    acc += val.count;
    return acc;
  }
};
```

In component:

```
const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);
const total = getCartTotal(cart);

<Link to="/cart">
  <Badge badgeContent={total} color="primary">
    <ShoppingCartOutlined />
  </Badge>
</Link>
```

You can create selectors for cart and cart total:

```
import {createSelector} from 'reselect';
// if you're already using @reduxjs/toolkit:
// import {createSelector} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSelector = (state) => state.cart;
const cartTotalSelector = createSelector(
  cartSelector,
  state => getCartTotal(state);
);
```

In component:

```
const total = useSelector(cartTotalSelector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your reducer first.

```
    if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
        // Land on a new state
        // Refine the new state
        // Return it
      }
    }
```

You need to take your time to do the above three steps, the reason why it's not working is you did too fast :)

```
        const newState = {
           ...state, cartItems.action.payload
        }
        newState.total = newState.cartItems.reduce((acc,val) =>{
            acc += val.count;
            return acc
        },0)
        return newState
    }
```

Doesn't matter how you do it, focus on the `newState` not `state`. It does seem everything can be done in one step, but there's order of things you need to pay attention to.

Comment: your answer is also right :). Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

As best practice the store shouldn't calculate anything but rather infer the next state from the current and combine them as needed via the action payload.

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, EMPTY_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../actions/types';
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
    count: 0,
}
export default function(state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: [action.payload, ...state.cart],
                count: state.count + 1
            }
        case EMPTY_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: [],
                count: 0
            }
        case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.filter((item, i) => i !== action.payload.index),
                count: state.count - 1
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```